# phplist installation files copy issue

Tags: php, phplist

I want to use phpList when user signs up in my website. 
Currently i am working in local.  To install phpList should i only copy to content of public_html/lists/ folder or whole public_html/lists folder into my local folder.

I tried this. 
1)
I am bit confused here. Because i tried both in documentation it says you need to copy the content of the public_html/lists/. When i am doing this it successfully installed but when i try to create new subscriber page and try to save changes it give me this error "**The requested URL /lists/admin/ was not found on this server**."

2) When i copied lists/ folder into local server and when i tried open admin page it displays this. it hasn't even shown installation process which it normally does(database initialization).

[image]

To install phpList into local what should be copied into local folder?

Comment: Looks like you have some missing tables in your mysql database, thats what I understand from the screenshot

Comment: about which error are you suggesting this ? first or second?

Comment: 2) where it says update error 1146.. and its a configuration store t able which must be an important one

Comment: how can i manually create all the tables ?  When i installed it first time it asked me to initialize database when i opened up host/admin.

Comment: does the script comes with sql dump?

Comment: first i didn't have to do anything. It created tables itself.

Comment: yes there is sql dump. By running it stopped me giving the errors displayed at the top. But i am not able to login in using username "admin" and password "phplist". Because i don't have a single row in admin table.

Comment: You can login to phpmyadmin or mysql command line and create an admin account

Comment: I wasn't talking about phpMyAdmin's admin account. I am talking about phpList's admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after installing a second instance of PHPlist. The way I was able to fix it was by rebooting my server entirely. Upon logging in, I got the standard installation page. (Otherwise, I continued to receive the missing tables and invalid login page, even when rebooting XAMMP on a Windows Server.)